# How do I remove twentyten without ruining what I did?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-twenty-ten

I created a blog with the twenty ten theme. I understand there are issues with upgrading WP with this default theme. It overwrites what you did. Is there a way to fix this with starting over.

How would I change something like this?
Ex.

```
<?php else : ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Answer (score 5):

Twenty Ten modifications will be overwritten with upgrades so you should be using a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of Twenty Ten instead of modifying it directly. There really is no way to stop the upgrade/overwrite without renaming the theme and putting it in a different folder with a different name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did that. I created a new folder, renamed the templates to have my new child theme and it got overwritten. Now what I did was renamed the theme and then renamed all the places where twenty ten is on the templates and in the function file. Its seemed to have worked, so far.

Comment: Glad it's working. Why don't you accept the answer since it's solved your issue.

Comment: Because he never does. :/